Can I change default hover color for only one widget in Flutter?
I'm trying to change or quit the default color when hovering a widget in Flutter web, in specific with showMenu function like this: `
items: items.map(
  (item) {
    return PopupMenuItem<String>(
      value: item,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: widthItems,
        child: _HoverableMenuItem(
          text: item,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList(),`

and i tried to use MouseRegion to change the item color, like this
MouseRegion(
    onEnter: (_) => setState(() => _isHovered = true),
    onExit: (_) => setState(() => _isHovered = false),
    child: Container(
      color: _isHovered ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1) : Colors.transparent,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 15,
        horizontal: 0,
      ),
      child: Text(
        widget.text,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )

it works in some way, but there is still the default grey color behind when hovering , and i want to know if there is a way to hide it or just change it without quit completely the hover styles in my app

Anything with a Color-type parameter can use a WidgetStateColor which can be programmed to automatically respond to hover state.  You don't need the mouse stuff... it'll be automatic.

Do you think that something like it could be work for you?
           Center(
              child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onHover: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  colorHover = val ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow;
                });
              },
              onTap: () {},
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                color: colorHover,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                child: Container(
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),

Need to declare   Color colorHover = Colors.yellow;
More here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html
